# How to fetch the html content inside div with class=container in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to fetch the HTML content inside the class 'container'. After searching I am able to write some code but I have not been able to fetch the html content needed.

It will be better if I can do it using `id` than `class`.

My `edit.component.ts` function is shown below:

```
selectDiv() {
     //create a new HTMLElement from nativeElement
    var hElement: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement;

    //now you can simply get your elements with their class name
    var allDivs = hElement.getElementsByClassName('container');

    //do something with selected elements
    console.log(allDivs);
  }
```

My `edit.component.html` code is below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button (click)="selectDiv()">select div</button>

   <div id="container" class="container">   
<p id="alert" contenteditable="true">
 EDIT ME
</p>
</div>
```

And what I see in my console:

[image]

I just simply want to have the html content.

Comment: The html is there just copy it from the window

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `getElementsByClassName` , there might be possibilities of multiple classes. So you are getting it in Array. Try it like

```
var allDivs = hElement.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
```

This will give you the first element containing `container` class.

Comment: I am getting this in console - https://www.dropbox.com/s/gane3aoyi44dgvh/Screenshot%202017-05-29%2012.18.12.png?dl=0 , why is it showing `_ng-content-c1` with div and p tag, i dont want that ? and if i want only the inside stuff of `<div class="container">`

Comment: That is by default added by angular. Don't worry about that.

Comment: I have to export this code as html pages i hope there will be no issues in my exported pages, i have added `contenteditable="true"` in the `div` like this - `<div class="container"  contenteditable="true">` , when i am getting value in variable how can i remove the `contenteditable="true"` from its div ?

Comment: Please be clear on your question. Update your question with the detail so that we can get more detail. If you put something in comment section noone's gonna know about what exactly is the issue

Comment: I am sorry but i was simply trying to say, while fetching the data is it possible to remove a class or property from the div

Comment: You ask question that's fine. But if you are having another question then you should ask it separately.  And this is how Stack Overflow works. So I request you If you have same issue please update your question and if you got solution of this question and have another one related to this then ask separately. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145362/discussion-between-the-dictator-and-user2828442).